# chrome declarativeNetRequest api - ruleset update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to write a custom ad blocker for an enterprise project. I've read the chrome extension declaratuveNetRequest api and it seems to be a good choice but I have some doubt about it. After some research I've seen that most ad blockers that are distributed into the CWS use this api to block ads, they will also manage the automatic update of the rules used to block ads, my doubt are on this aspect.

Since the rules that will be used are part of the extension and are packed with it, how I can manage the update of the rules used from the extension using easylist? I've found a good tool that can convert easylist to a valid ruleset that can be used from the extension, the problem is that I don't want to update each time the rules manually using the tool and then release an update of the extension.

I've seen that there is an api method to update rules but it's limited to 5000 rules and if I understand well the rules added will be added permanently and are counted as part of the max limit of rules that can be declared?

Can anyone that have experience with this api give me some tips about implementation of rules and relative updates?

Comment: This API is intentionally designed that way. While they pretend to do it for performance, they didn't provide any verifiable measurements. Our only choice while making a ManifestV3 Chrome extension is to bend and do as they say i.e. update extensions when the rules are updated. The alternative is to use chrome policies to declare the extension as force-installed so it'll have access to the blocking webRequest.

Comment: @wOxxOm as I know manifest v3 isn't released at the moment but from your comment I assume that it will be available soon? For the chrome policies, what do you mean with force installed?

Comment: 1) It is available in beta, dev, and canary channels. 2) Look it up to see the instructions.